# why my Contract address 0 value on etherscan

Tags: contract-development, erc-20, wallets, uniswap, coinbase

Transaction Hash:
0xcacbecb6c8be10317e27784c7afd33fa52f43df6e31fcc4e0a253b274201bc56

Address

0x1B2cB9A600F80D8cDb529F8D448b9010B0C978c6

Answer (score 1):

If you go to https://etherscan.io/address/0x1b2cb9a600f80d8cdb529f8d448b9010b0c978c6 you can see it has the tokens which were transferred to it. The address has no Ethers, as nobody has transferred Ethers there - that's why "Ether value" is 0.

Comment: thank u for answer but i sand wrong contract                     0x6B3595068778DD592e39A122f4f5a5cF09C90fE2   this one is

Comment: that is the token contract, that's not your contract.

Comment: how can i get back that token from thecontract didnt work now       but the money in my wallet already be send

Comment: the things i did wrong that is no swap token to eth   and i just direct send to eth address

Comment: @JamesQs The tokens are in the 0x1b2... address. To move them you need to send a transaction from that address and to do that you need some ether to pay for the fees.

Comment: how can i send a transaction to that address

Comment: i am new for smart contract